# Create ubuntu user with home folder located in www and restrict ssh access using ChrootDirectory to that folder

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, laravel

I posted this on stackoverflow and was told to post here:

I am running a Ubuntu remote dev server, heavily restricted (due to compliance) environment which i previously had configured correctly for many devs a year ago but forgotten it.

On this sever i log in as root and have my own folder in

```
/var/www/me/laravel
```

and everything works fine, i am now adding new users to this server but can't get it working.

In this case i want to create a user called "mike" and allow him to have full read, write and execute permissions in his folder (to run multiple applications laravel and angular) located in

```
/var/www/mike
```

For applications served by apache.

mike will remote ssh onto the server using his ubuntu username / password and be restricted to his folder and only work on projects it's subfolders, not being able to move outside of his home directory but have full control all the folders in this directory to remotely develop.

So far i have:

```
sudo useradd -m -d /var/www/mike mike
sudo passwd mike
sudo chmod 700 /var/www/mike
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Then i add the below to the file and restart the ssh service:

```
add:Match User mike 
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    #ForceCommand internal-sftp
    ChrootDirectory /var/www/mike

sudo service ssh restart
```

if i enable

```
ChrootDirectory /var/www/mike
```

mike cannot log into the server, if i comment out ChrootDirectory mike can log in fine but still navigate into root, just not other users folders if i give them each chmod 700 but then it messes with apache to serve the application in those folders.

i've tired following this:

```
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542440/how-does-chrootdirectory-and-a-users-home-directory-work-together
```

and i have set

```
 /var/www/mike
```

as

```
 chown root:root /var/www/mike
```

with

```
 chmod 755 /var/www/mike
```

then created a folder

```
 /var/www/mike/home
```

and gave it it

```
chown mike: /var/www/mike/home
chmod 750 /var/www/mike/home
usermod =d /var/www/mike/home mike
```

if i try then set

```
 ChrootDirectory /var/www/%u
```

it allows me to log in but in the auth.log after the session opened for mike, i see

```
 error: /dev/pts/0: No such file or directory
```

Also in regards to laravel set up with this chroot i cannot remember if i should add

```
usermod -a -G users www-data
```

Then i need to allow Apache www-data to serve this directories public folder and have the correct permissions for laravel storage, cache etc to execute by apache.

I tried

```
cd /var/www/mike/home/laravel

sudo chown -R mike:www-data
```

to give both the user and the webserver permissions:

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;   
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

so the webserver has rights to read and write to storage and cache

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Can any one tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi! Interesting question! Just guessing, but a restriction on the directory used as ChrootDirectory is that all components of the pathname must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group. Is that true in your case?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if they are or not - i created a brand new user from scratch for testing the /var/www/mike directory is root:root with 755 permissions - then the home folder which i can ssh into but hangs up due to the error: /dev/pts/0: No such file or directory.  Is all this about mouting dev/pts in /var/www/mike/dev/pts ?

Sorry i'm not super strong on linxu so trying to figure it out the hard way :(

Comment: What do the `journalctl` logs say when user mike tries to log in? Also BTW I'm not familiar with ssh's ChrootDirectory but there may be some clues here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542440/how-does-chrootdirectory-and-a-users-home-directory-work-together